# PHP как из обработчика обновить страницу

Tags: php

Как можно с помощью PHP обновить страницу? 
Имеется ввиду при каком-то действии, обновить удаленно страницу, не ту на которой совершается действие.

Comment: Смута какая-то. Может опишите какую задачу вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: У оператора открыта страница со списком заказов, в базу добавляется заказ и страница оператора обновляется после добавления заказа в базу.

Comment: На стороне оператора аяксом проверять наличие новых заказов. Если есть - добавляем в DOM, если нет - сидим и ждём заказов.

Comment: @Asen, что?

Comment: Что за чушь? Как можно обновить страницу, которой не существует?

Comment: @Tchort - начните ваши великие деяния в IT с понимания таких вещей, как сервер и клиент, жить станет намного проще и столь глупых вопросов возникать не будет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть у меня пример реализации - подгрузка новых заявок:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval('show()', 60000); // 1 minute
    show();
    blink(600000, 1000)
});

function show()
{
   $.ajax({
       url: "/ajax/",
       type: 'POST',
       cache: false,
       success: function(html){
           $("#tickets_fieldlist").html(html);
       }
   });
}

function blink(time, interval){
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        $(".blink").css("opacity", "0.01");
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $(".blink").css("opacity", "1");
        }, 300);
    }, interval);
    window.setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(timer);}, time);
}
```

При загрузке документа с задержкой вызывается show(), функция blink() делает так, чтобы элемент в новой заявке (там лампочкой обозначается) моргал, когда заявка новая.

Answer (score 3):

я бы сделал это примерно так

```
1. НА странице со списком заказов пишем Ajax запрос на существование новых заказов.
2. Если есть новые заказы опять Ajax запрос на подгрузку новых заказов
```

Comment: Поддерживаю @Ale_x

Comment: Зачем делать два запроса? В одном запросе можно и проверить, и, если есть, подтянуть новые заказы. В остальном алгоритм рабочий.

Comment: 2 запроса на тот случай что можно делать не автоматическую подгрузку заказов, а просто показать моргающую картинку с текстом есть новые заказы.

Comment: Т.е. для случаев когда заказы приходят большими пачками и/или БД очень медленная? В таком случае согласен.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону Comet. Или Node.js. По самой специфике http работает в ответ на запрос со стороны клиента (=браузера), т.е. если пользователь сам не инициировал обновление страницы с запросом на сервер за данными, то ничего происходить не будет. Можно с интервалом «долбиться» запросами на сервер с вопросом, были ли изменения или открыть тоннель и ждать ответа от сервера, что, собственно, и делает Comet.

P.S. Знающие люди, если не прав — исправьте меня.

Comment: Если он ajax не рубит, то Node.js будет очень сложно. Пусть начинает копать так сказать с низов